# Почему не открывается модульное окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я в js не силен только изучаю и ничего не понимаю пока что. мб кто подскажет почему не открывается модульное окно? брал код с этого сайта https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html там открывает у меня нет в чем проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../_static/js/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

<script>
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
myDialog = new Dialog({
    title: "My Dialog",
    content: "Test content.",
    style: "width: 300px"
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
 <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: есть ошибки в консоли?

Comment: вероятнее всего ошибка с 'путями', быть может данные файлы находятся не так как там написано?